# BottomSheetDialogFragment setText textView erorr

Tags: java, android, dialog

for my app I need to show a bottom dynamic dialog. I found this solution:

```
public class bottomBar extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
   public TextView txtLabel;

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_bar, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    txtLabel = contentView.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
}
```

wuith bottom_bar.xml like this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" />
```

From my MainActivity I call my dialog, and I try to change the txtLabel text this way:

```
bottomBar bb = new bottomBar();

                bb.txtLabel.setText(String.format("mytext %s %s?" , var1, var2));
                bb.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bb.getTag());
```

When I try to call setText() the app crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null objectbb.txtLabel
```

Can you help me?

note: if I change order I have the same result:

```
bb.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bb.getTag());
bb.txtLabel.setText(String.format("mytext %s %s?" , var1, var2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inflated layout is bottom_bar.xml .But your layout name is layout_bar.xml . Check that properly

Comment: Thanks, It was a mistake of in the text. Correct!

Comment: unfortunately the problem is not this

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `new bottomBar()` then your attribute `public TextView txtLabel;` isn't initialized. you should try to show() it first in order to initialized this attribute.